# Post product with product image in shopify using php-curl

Tags: php, php-curl, shopify-api

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
$images = $_POST['images'];
    
$productData = [
    "product" => [ 
    "variants" => [
        [           
           "price"=>"$price"
        ]
    ],
    "images" => [
        [
           "src"=> "$images"
        ]
    ],
]
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://{shop-name}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/products.json?access_token={access-token}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($productData));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo'<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo'</pre>';
curl_close($ch);
```

I was trying to send my product details via php-curl but when I send it, it shows the data in the site but product's image and price is not showing in it and it's not showing any kind of error.

Comment: Do a `json_encode($productData)` instead of http_build_query

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: when i apply json_encode($productData) instead of http_build_query then code returning this error  {"errors":{"product":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}     and when i apply http_build_query then code return  successfully msg but when i check my site there is no image and price of that product but name , description,vendor etc. visible.

Comment: What does var_dump($_POST) return?

Comment: Don't know about var_dump($_POST), I didn't apply.

Comment: Apply and check what does it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$post_data=[
 "product"=> [
        "title"=> "Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
        "body_html"=> "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
        "vendor"=> "Burton",
        "product_type"=> "Snowboard",
        "images"=> [
            [
                "src"=> "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://your-development-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/products.json',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($post_data),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token: {access_token}',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

References: https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/product#post-products

Comment: this code is returning (Bad Request)

Comment: Check now! I have updated the code.